# Flutter type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast

Tags: flutter, dart

I've problem with my some json data.
When I debug my code I'have error this line in my code:
return TestHistoryEntity.fromJson(result.data as Map<String, dynamic>);
But in the TestHistoryEntitiy.formJson have below line

```
  if (json['test'] != null) {
      test = MonthWiseTests.fromJson(json['test'] as Map<String, dynamic>);
    }
```

This line occurs problem:           `test = MonthWiseTests.fromJson(json['test'] as Map<String, dynamic>);`
I have this error: Flutter type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast
As you see test is List but MonthWiseTests.fromJson get Map<String, dynamic> map) type. But I can not manage this how can I solve this problem. Please help me.

These are the files needed to catch the error

This is my Json File:

```
{
"filter1": [
    "loops",
    "custom test"
],
"subjects": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Maths"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Physics"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Chemistry"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Biology"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "History"
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Political Science"
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Geography"
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "Economics"
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "name": "General"
    }
],
"test": [
    {
        "month": "2023 March",
        "tests": [
            {
                "date": "17,Fri,11:45",
                "paused": false,
                "progress": true,
                "subjectId": null,
                "testId": 1,
                "testType": "Concept",
                "text1": "Reflection of Light",
                "text2": "Light-Reflection and Refraction",
                "text3": "Physics",
                "userTestId": 196
            },
            {
                "date": "17,Fri,11:45",
                "paused": false,
                "progress": false,
                "subjectId": null,
                "testId": 1,
                "testType": "Concept",
                "text1": "Reflection of Light",
                "text2": "Light-Reflection and Refraction",
                "text3": "Physics",
                "userTestId": 197
            },
           ....
        ]
    }
]
```

}

This is my TestEntity Class:

```
class TestHistoryEntity {
  TestHistoryEntity({this.subjects, this.test});

  TestHistoryEntity.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['subjects'] != null) {
      subjects = <Subjects>[];
      (json['subjects'] as List).forEach((v) {
        subjects!.add(Subjects.fromJson(v as Map<String, dynamic>));
      });
    }
    if (json['filter1'] != null) {
      filter1 = <String>[];
      (json['filter1'] as List).forEach((v) {
        filter1!.add(v.toString());
      });
    }
    if (kDebugMode) {
      print("FILTER_TEST");
      print(filter1);
    }

    if (json['test'] != null) {

      test = MonthWiseTests.fromJson(json['test'] as Map<String, dynamic>);

    }
  }

  List<Subjects>? subjects;
  MonthWiseTests? test;
  List<String>? filter1;

  /*  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    if (subjects != null) {
      data['subjects'] = subjects!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    if (test != null) {
      data['test'] = test!((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  } */
}
```

And MothWise Class:

```
class MonthWiseTests {
  MonthWiseTests({
    this.month,
    this.tests,
  });

  factory MonthWiseTests.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return MonthWiseTests(
      month: map.keys.first,
      tests: map[map.keys.first] != null
          ? List<Test>.from(
              (map[map.keys.first] as List<dynamic>).map<Test?>(
                (x) => Test.fromJson(x as Map<String, dynamic>),
              ),
            )
          : null,
    );
  }
  String? month;
  List<Test>? tests;

  MonthWiseTests copyWith({
    String? month,
    List<Test>? tests,
  }) {
    return MonthWiseTests(
      month: month ?? this.month,
      tests: tests ?? this.tests,
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return <String, dynamic>{
      'month': month,
      'tests': tests?.map((x) => x.toJson()).toList(),
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are absolutely sure that test in your JSON file will always be a list with a single item in it you could do something like this

```
test = MonthWiseTests.fromJson(json['test'][0] as Map<String, dynamic>);
```

the problem is that json['test'] returns a ***List<Map<String,dynamic>>*** instead of ***Map<String,dynamic>*** that why you cannot cast it to Map<String,dynamic> directly so instead access the first element by indexing the list returned then cast it

If test would have multiple elements in it (it doesn't appear so by the structure of the JSON file) you would have to either change MonthWiseTests to accept List or make a for loop over json['test']

---

**To solve  `I/flutter (16798): │ ⛔ type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast`**

it appears that in `MonthWiseTests.fromJson` function in getting ***tests*** details you have used `map[map.keys.first]` which gets you the first key in the map which is `month` not `tests` and the value of `map[month]` is a string thus when you try to cast it to a List `map[map.keys.first] as List<dynamic>` it throws an error you should instead change every `map[map.keys.first]` in tests to `map['tests']` instead

Comment: Thank you for your response, test area like this :
test:{{month: .., tests: {}},{month: .., tests: {}},{month: .., tests: {}}}
Whe I try your suggestion I get: I/flutter (16798): │ ⛔ type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast

Comment: I've been trying for 2 days but I couldn't find a solution. Please help.

Comment: Is there any answer ?

Comment: @hobik check the edited answer hopefully it should work

Comment: Hi thank you for your suggestions, yes you are right. I change this parameter map[map.keys.first] to map['tests'] and I changed month parameter type, but I have question If I have lots of month information in test area how can I see because we type (json['test'][0] as Map<String, dynamic>); so we every time we have first element

Comment: Okey I found the answer for my last question. Your suggestion help me a lot tahnk you for everything.